# Pulling Part of string only with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I pull back only the string after the '%' sign from a column? I have a string like this:

> 0.010% Senior notes, due May 12, 2016

I would like to return this:

> Senior notes, due May 12, 2016

So far I've tried the following SQL to get this working, but it isn't correct.

`right(name, CHARINDEX('[%]',name))`

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far?

Comment: The output i am looking for is "Senior notes, due May 12, 2016"

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: The column name being the 'Name' i have tried this code,, but it doesn't woks.. right(name, CHARINDEX('[%]',name))

Comment: Micorsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will Give You Expected Output :

```
    SELECT SUBSTRING('0.010% Senior notes, due May 12, 2016',
           CHARINDEX('%','0.010% Senior notes, due May 12, 2016')+1,
           LEN('0.010% Senior notes, due May 12, 2016')
    )
```

As

```
SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length ) will produce substring  
- Gives Specific String between Start and Length

CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind ,expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )
- Gives Index of Specific Character

LEN ( string_expression )
- Length Of String
```

Output

```
  Senior notes, due May 12, 2016
```

Answer (score 4):

The script following will bring back everything after '%'

```
DECLARE @string nvarchar(200)

SET @string = '0.010% Senior notes, due May 12, 2016'

SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT(@string, CHARINDEX('%', REVERSE(@string))-1)))
```

RESULT : Senior notes, due May 12, 2016

Hope this helps.

Comment: Only a pleasure @TayyabZA

Comment: I've not heard of or seen `REVERSE()` before. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @TayyabZA, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.